# i want to getchar twice but i cant

Tags: c, getchar

```
int main()
{
    int r, c;
    r = getchar();
    c = getchar();
    putchar(r);
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

After it reads in `r`, the program outputs `r` and quits. I want it to ask for `c` and input it but how come it doesnt do that?

Answer (score 3):

Are you entering the characters on the same line, or on 2 lines?

`getchar()` will wait until you press enter, and then start parsing the characters. If you have entered 2 characters on 2 different lines, it will read the first character *and then the `\n` character*.

What I mean is, the following input:

```
a
b
```

is equivalent to `"a\nb"`.

`getchar()` will grab the `\n` instead of `b`, and print `a\n\n`.

You want to type both characters, and only then hit enter.

Comment: To clarify: `getchar` does not wait until you hit enter; the terminal application buffers input until you hit enter and then sends everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably typing <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The first `getchar()` reads the character `X`, and the second `getchar()` reads a newline generated when you press Enter. Type both your characters without pressing Enter.