# Putting an enter key when getchar(); is executed

Tags: c, character, newline, stdin, getchar

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = getchar();
    printf("%d", a);
}

output

10
```

This is When I wrote code like this and stroked only an 'enter' key on console. Keystroke 'enter' effect 1. put a '\n' in buffer 2. return that value to getchar sequently(It's what I am understanding about the situation). How can it possible? This result is like pressing enter key twice. I found a related question [getchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609267/i-want-to-getchar-twice-but-i-cant), but I couldn't find something to help me understand.

Comment: With the code shown, you should not need to press the enter key twice. The terminal should recognize the first one as ending the line and will "send" the (otherwise empty) line to your program.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Then do you mean that putting any one key is sufficient to let the value '\n' return to the getchar? or for only enter key?

Comment: If you press *only* the `Enter` key, then the newline will be the only character added to the input buffer.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Ok, an input buffer has '\n' by pressing only the `Enter` key, but how does variable `a` have '\n'? It's by pressing only the key `Enter`. Isn't it?

Comment: Are you running from Linux or Windows.  They behave differently.

Comment: @cup I am using Windows.

Comment: Simplified, the terminal write the newline into your programs input buffer. Your program (through the `getchar` function) reads that newline from the input buffer and writes it into the `a` variable. From the terminal or console, all the way though the operating system and drivers and buffers and into your variable `a`, it's the same newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This result is like pressing enter key twice.

It is the behavior of `getchar()`, when it encounters a newline character `\n` *only* in `stdin`, what makes the difference.

---

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = getchar();
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

shows the appropriate output of:

```
10
```

when you input *one* "Enter" keystroke.

---

`getchar()` waits for input until it encounters a newline `\n` in `stdin` then returns the character values until that moment; If `\n` was the only character encountered, `getchar()` stops scanning and returns this newline character and actually this is what was happen.

In this particular case, You do not need to push "Enter" a second time to affect that `getchar()` stops scanning.

Comment: Does your answer intend that firstly press enter key send buffer '\n' and secondly someone recognize '\n' is in buffer, and return '\n' to getchar?

Comment: @lev.1code `getchar()` looks for chracters in `stdin` until it finds a newline character `\n`. If it encounters the newline character, it stops scanning and flushes the character values so far to `a` but leaves `\n` in the buffer. If it only encounters `\n` than it stops scanning and returns this newline character to `a`. No need to input a second newline character.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio, are you sure that encountering `\n` after some characters it flushes everything but `\n` leaving it in the buffer? From my tests, `\n` is getting flushed too.